# How to remove the "Follow," "Unfollow" and "Join Tumblr" buttons on a Tumblr site?

Tags: tumblr

From what I understand, the Tumblr buttons at the top right of any Tumblr site are auto-inserted via iFrame. This means I cannot directly delete these buttons by editing the HTML. But I want them gone. I don't want my website to be an advertisement for the blogging platform.

How can I remove the "Follow" (or "Unfollow") and "Join Tumblr" (or "Dashboard" + Mail) buttons from my site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Go to your blog
2. Click "Customize" in the upper left
3. Deselect "Promote Tumblr!"

Comment: YES very very helpful!!! Thank you so so so so much! Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 7):

This procedure has changed *slightly* since this was answered:

1. In Tumblr Dashboard, click on the *Account* → **Edit Appearance**
2. Click on **Edit Theme** button (same **Customize**)
3. Scroll to the button and click **Advanced Settings**
4. Uncheck **Promote Tumblr!**

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to uncheck this option doesn't do the job anymore.

Comment: Worked for me! Should be the accepted answer now!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but the simpler procedure other answers explain didn't work in my case.

Following [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41566508/6398434), I had to inspect the page and find the first appearance of an `iframe` below the body of the page then take the full class and set it to `display: none`.

Here is the CSS code that worked for me on PC using the default Tumblr theme and not logged:

```
.tmblr-iframe-compact .tmblr-iframe--unified-controls {display:none!important;}
```

You can find the custom CSS recipient on the "Advanced options" menu.

Additionally, I had to add [this other piece of code](https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/3vtb1z/removing_openinstall_the_app_header_toolbar_from/cy912bj) to make it work on Android:

```
tumblr_controls, .tmblr-iframe{display:none!important;}
```

Pay attention because you might not find an easy way to edit your theme anymore, but you can still find the panel by just clikcing on your blog from the dashboard or directly at www.tumblr.com/customize/[yourblog].

Answer (score 0):

I used these 2 pieces of code by JorgeAmVF in the "add css" option on the advanced menu. Worked! 08/2022. It overrode the code without deleting or changing any additional code.

Here is the CSS code that worked for me on PC using the default Tumblr theme and not logged:

```
.tmblr-iframe-compact .tmblr-iframe--unified-controls {display:none!important;}
```

You can find the custom CSS recipient on the "Advanced options" menu.

Additionally, I had to add this other piece of code to make it work on Android:

```
tumblr_controls, .tmblr-iframe{display:none!important;}
```